# html link to the middle of another page

Tags: php, html

Fellow Coders,
I would like to know if there is html code that can link to the middle of another html/php page, not on the same page.
I've searched many websites but all I find is the code to link to the middle of the same page. 
I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just link to the page and use the hashtag like you would if you linking to the middle of the same page:

```
<a href="otherpage.html#middleofpage">link</a>
```

Comment: Note that `middleofpage` has to exist as an anchor (`<a name="middleofpage">`) or an element ID somewhere on the target page for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="pagename.php#anchor">link text</a>
```

http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html

Comment: Please add more context to your post just adding code and a link does not an answer make.

Answer (score 1):

If on the other page is no anchor (`<a name="">` for example), then there's no way to do so.

If yes, you can use URL#anchor-name.

Comment: You don't need an anchor.  Any element with an `id` is sufficient.  I.e. `<a href="test.html#test">Go to test.html and scroll to #test</a>` would move to the element `<div id='test'>` on the test.html page

Comment: Yes. name, id these all are anchors. (I said: for example)

Answer (score 0):

You define the name of the section you want to link to.

The you reference that link as #name.